# Connection refused when trying to load HDFS file from Spyder

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, spyder

I am working with Apache SPARK and Python (pyspark) in a Python IDE named Spyder. I am trying to load a file from HDFS like this:

```
hdfs_file = sc.textFile(hdfs_path)
```

I ensure that the path is correct and the file exists, but when I execute the command I get the next error-line:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o24.partitions.
: java.net.ConnectException: Call From XXXX.local/127.0.0.1 to localhost:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
```

What can I do to load correctly files from HDFS?

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

It was only starting-up the hdfs server.